# Memory increases with each request when using AutoMapper's ProjectTo with expand option

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-5

I'm building a .NET 5 REST API based on CQRS/MediatR and I noticed a linear memory increase when stress testing my application. I did some profiling and saw a large number of object instances from the namespace `System.Linq.Expression` was taking up all the space. All these instances are related to the `MapperConfiguration` of AM.

I use AutoMapper to map my entities to the DTOs, to do so I mainly use the following `ProjectTo` extension method :

```
public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectTo<TDestination>(this IQueryable source, IConfigurationProvider configuration, object parameters, params Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>[] membersToExpand);
```

After some testing, I noticed that the memory problem is only happening when providing `membersToExpand` inside the `ProjectTo` method.

When providing an "expand" and calling the related endpoint, it's like the expression of the mapping is created each time but never freed. As they stay, they accumulates in memory and add as the query is called.

Here is a screenshot of the memory state comparing two snapshots :

- The first one after one call to the endpoint
- The second one after five more call to the same endpoint (without changing anything)

[image: Memory comparison between first and sixth call]

I wouldn't mind the memory usage thinking it may be some kind of cache used by AM to have better response time but the problem is that the more memory is used the slower it gets for my API to respond to the request (4ms at the start to 90ms after the stress test). I guess AM has a hard time searching inside so many stored expressions. As soon as I stop using the "expand" system, the responses are again instantaneous (4ms).

Last point is that when the application pool is recycled (and the memory cleared), the API responds again in full speed at 4ms (with the expand).

I searched online for hours to see if I had missed a specific AM configuration related to caches or something, but found nothing.

**Does anyone has an idea, similar experience or more information about this behaviour ?**

PS : As you can see, I use AM with DI (using the package for DI and `.AddAutoMapper` method)

Below, some code samples from my application :

`RoleByProfileDto` (`RoleDto` has nothing particular and `ReverseMap` is only here for "translation" purpose) :

```cs
    public class RoleByProfileDto : RoleDto
    {
        public ProfileRoleDto ProfileRole { get; set; }

        public void Mapping(AM.Profile profile)
        {
            int profileId = default;

            profile.CreateMap<Role, RoleByProfileDto>()
                .ForMember(dto =>
                    dto.ProfileRole, opts =>
                        opts.MapFrom(r => r.ProfileRoles.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.ProfileId == profileId))
                )
                .IncludeBase<Role, RoleDto>()
                .ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

Handler of the said request :

```cs
    public class GetRoleByProfileAndIdQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetRoleByProfileAndIdQuery, RoleByProfileDto>
    {
        private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly AM.IMapper _mapper;

        public GetRoleByProfileAndIdQueryHandler(IApplicationDbContext context, AM.IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<RoleByProfileDto> Handle(GetRoleByProfileAndIdQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var dto = await _context.Roles
                .Where(r =>
                    r.Id == request.RoleId
                    && r.ProfileRoles.Any(pr =>
                        pr.ProfileId == request.ProfileId
                    )
                )
                .ProjectTo(
                    _mapper.ConfigurationProvider,
                    new { profileId = request.ProfileId },
                    request.Expand.GetExpandMemberList(ExpandMappings)
                )
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (dto == null)
            {
                throw new NotFoundException(
                    nameof(Role),
                    new List<string>() { nameof(Profile), nameof(Role) },
                    new List<object>() { request.ProfileId, request.RoleId }
                );
            }

            return dto;
        }

        private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<RoleByProfileAndIdExpand, Expression<Func<RoleByProfileDto, object>>> ExpandMappings =
            new Dictionary<RoleByProfileAndIdExpand, Expression<Func<RoleByProfileDto, object>>>
            {
                { RoleByProfileAndIdExpand.ProfileRole, d => d.ProfileRole }
            };
    }
```

The method used to build the expand array that is provided to the `ProjectTo` :

```cs
        public static Expression<Func<TDto, object>>[] GetExpandMemberList<TEnum, TDto>(
            this IList<TEnum> selectedExpands,
            IReadOnlyDictionary<TEnum, Expression<Func<TDto, object>>> mappings
        )
            where TEnum : Enum
            where TDto : BaseDto
        {
            if (selectedExpands != null && selectedExpands.Any())
                return selectedExpands.Select(e => mappings[e]).ToArray();
            else
                return Array.Empty<Expression<Func<TDto, object>>>();
        }
```

Comment: When is `RoleByProfileDto::Mapping` called?

Comment: Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.

Comment: @Stefan the mapping is done inside the `ProjectTo` method directly by AM. Here the type is inferred because we use it in the expand part.

Comment: @Lucian Bargaoanu I'll try as soon as possible and I'll give you a feedback.

Comment: I just want to make sure you're not calling `profile.CreateMap` prior to every map.

Comment: I misunderstood you comment sorry. The mapping methods of all my DTO are called in AM Profile constructor. So they are only called one time during the startup.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I tried with the release `8.1.2-alpha.0.8` of the `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` and it seems that the leak has gone ! I suppose you already fixed what was broken in the `8.1.1` ? I've some bits of code that are not really compatible with this version though. So I guess I'll wait for the official release to see what I'll have to change. Anyway thank you very much ! Feel free to make an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Yes, that was fixed a long time ago. I don't expect significant changes before 11.0. Check [the upgrade guide](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/upgrade_guide/docs/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This leak is fixed in the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build. Details [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3473/files#r658618557).

Comment: Any idea on when the release 11.0 of AutoMapper will be available ? I'd like to avoid using pre-release if possible but having a memory leak is less than desirable. Last question, do you think it would be safe to use the last pre-release build in production ? I guess each build goes through testing.

Comment: As safe as any release.:) I'm certainly using it. There is no special testing for a release.